# C# WebBrowser in loop and Fiddlercore

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, fiddlercore

I use Fiddlercore to capture multiple url's at the same time inside a loop.

Example:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // I have 2 url 
    string arr = new string[]{ url1, url2 };
    foreach(var url in arr)
    {
       new Webbrowser().Navigate(url);
    }

    Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.AfterSessionComplete 
        += new Fiddler.SessionStateHandler(FiddlerApplication_AfterSessionComplete);
    }

    // I will catch 2 oSession contain same string "a/b/c" in 2 URL from 2 Webbrowser in loop 
   int Count = 0;
   void FiddlerApplication_AfterSessionComplete(Fiddler.Session oSession)
   {
       if(oSession.fullUrl.contain("a/b/c"))
       {
           Count+= 1;
           richtextbox1.AppendText("oSession.fullUrl" + "\n");
       }

       if(Count == 2)
       {
           Count = 0;
           StopFiddler();
       }
   }

void StopFiddler()
{
    Fiddler.FiddlerApplication.AfterSessionComplete 
        -= new Fiddler.SessionStateHandler(FiddlerApplication_AfterSessionComplete);
}
```

This works but I have a problem. Fiddlercore stops the capture session, but the web browser doesn't stop, it's still loading.

How to stop the WebBrowser from loading after I get what I need.

Answer (score 0):

Use [WebBrowser.Stop()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.stop(v=vs.110).aspx) to stop all loading.

> Cancels any pending navigation and stops any dynamic page elements, such as background sounds and animations.

**Edit:** Also, you need to save a reference to those WebBrowser controls you're creating, so that you can actually call the `Stop` method for them. The way you use them now is quite strange and might lead to problems down the line (actually it led to problems already).

Comment: How can i use WebBrowser.Stop() when I declare like that :  new Webbrowser().Navigate(url);